# No difference between TraditionalForm and StandardForm in Graph labels

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, traditional-form

`TraditionalForm` seems not to be working properly on Mathematica 11.3 when used in `Graph`. The following MWE

```
edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2};
GraphicsRow[{Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> ρ,
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive["StandardForm", 30]],
  Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> ρ, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive["TraditionalForm", 30]], 
  Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> ρ, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive["DisplayForm", 30]]}]
```

Produces the following output (I'm putting `StandardForm` for comparison)

[image: graph]

However, when I do

```
TraditionalForm[ρ]
```

The character output is that in the left image of [the character description](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Rho.html).

Then, I began to wonder, is it possible to use characters in `TraditionalForm` inside `Graph`s?

Comment: Should this work?  `"TraditionalForm"` is not a graphics directive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it should, since for instance ``"StandardForm"`` does work. I have updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put `"StandardForm"` or `"TraditionalForm"` inside the directive, it's using them as named styles, not as `StandardForm` or `TraditionalForm`.

The reason they look different, is because `"StandardForm"` (as a style) includes a specific font, while `"TraditionalForm"` doesn't:

```
In[122]:= Lookup[
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "StandardForm"}], FontFamily]

Out[122]= "Source Code Pro"

In[121]:= Lookup[
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "TraditionalForm"}], FontFamily]

Out[121]= Missing["KeyAbsent", FontFamily]
```

(Note that the font for `"StandardForm"` is actually a dynamic value; I hacked in what it looks like for me.)

This is why

```
Style[TraditionalForm[Sin[x]], FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"]
```

will show up in Comic Sans, while

```
Style[StandardForm[Sin[x]], FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"]
```

won't:

[image]

What "form" is used for the labels is determined by the `FormatType` option, using the default font for text in graphics:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> x^2, 2 -> Sqrt[x]}, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]
Graph[{1 -> 2}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> x^2, 2 -> Sqrt[x]}, FormatType -> StandardForm]
Graph[{1 -> 2}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> x^2, 2 -> Sqrt[x]}, FormatType -> InputForm]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) doesn't propagate the [`FormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatType) to the [`InsetBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InsetBox) objects used to typeset the labels. You can workaround this by including the right [`FontFamily`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontFamily) explicitly:

```
Graph[
    {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2},
    VertexLabels -> ρ, 
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily->"Times", "TraditionalForm", 30]
]
```

[image]